# Left Shifting a number

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

i performed a simple bit operation using `<<` on the variable `result` to set bit on the 32nd position..

`result = result | (1<<31);`

which should give the output as(in binary):

`0000000000000000000000000000000010000000000000000000000000000000`

and in decimal:

`2147483648`

but instead this was the output(in binary):

`1111111111111111111111111111111110000000000000000000000000000000`

and in decimal:

`-2147483648`

here is the code:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  int64_t result = 0;
  
  result = result | (1 << 31);  
  std::bitset<64> x(result);
  std::cout << x <<std:: endl;
  std::cout << result << std:: endl;
}
```

please help me find the error

Comment: use `1u << 31` or (`int64_t(1) << 31`).

Answer (score 8):

The literal `1` is treated as `int`. It seems `int` in your environment is 32-bit long and the result is sign-extended.

Add cast to `int64_t` before shifting to calculate in `int64_t`.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
  int64_t result = 0;
  
  result = result | (static_cast<int64_t>(1) << 31);  
  std::bitset<64> x(result);
  std::cout << x <<std:: endl;
  std::cout << result << std:: endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And please use only unsigned types for bitshifting.

Shifting signed types can have unpleasant side effects...